# Can I attach an electrical box to the outside of a wooden closet in my unfinished basement?

Tags: electrical, usa

I'm getting a sump pump installed and I need a new outlet which I'm hoping to install myself. The photo below shows where the panel is as well as the proposed outlet location and the path I'm planning to use to run the cable.

Is there any problem with attaching the outlet box to the wooden closet pictured? It's quite thick and solid so this seems fine, but I'm wondering if there's any potential code issues I might have missed.

[image: proposed cable run and outlet location]

**Edit**

I decided to run along the joist to the far side of the closet and then use EMT with a transition fitting to go the rest of the way. Inspector found no issues with the job.

Comment: What type of "cable"

Comment: @JACK Romex, but the final vertical drop will be in conduit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route you're showing in front of the closet would expose the NM cable to physical damage. However, you could run NB up to the joist above the panel, staple it along the joist past the closet and install a junction box. From there, down to the outlet with conduit and individual wires. Personally, in this case, I'd go conduit all the way.

Comment: Going up to the hoist and then down to conduit is what I was planning. I'm confused why a junction box would be required. In talking to my local inspector, it seemed that just a transition attached to the top of the conduit would be sufficient.

Comment: @MichaelMior  The junction box would be a nice transition with an NM clamp to box and conduit to box connectors.  What transition attachment was the inspector referring to?

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but I believe he meant [something like this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-ProConnex-1-2-in-Electrical-EMT-Die-Cast-Zinc-Transition-Coupling-Conduit-Fittings/3390632).

Comment: @MichaelMior  That would work well for EMT conduit.

Answer (score 3):

That route would be considered exposed to physical damage, so no exposed NM ("Romex") or UF Cables, you will need sch80 pvc or metal conduit.

NEC 210.8(A)(5) now requires all receptacles in basements be GFCI protected, some building departments take issue with that and make exceptions.

Comment: Wiremold would also suit for surface-mount wiring protection in most jurisdictions.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I hated installing that stuff so much in schools in the 1990's for computers that I just kind of hope that stuff flies under the radar under the general description of "metal conduit" and hope the OP doesn't even realize it's an option! :)

Comment: Interesting. The route appears to me to be very similar to the ones used for my hot water heater and furnace, neither of which are in conduit. Since the outlet will be for a sump pump, it will definitely be GFCI.

Comment: I didn't see the horizontal portion of the blue line as in the joist space, it looked to me like it was on the surface of the closet too. Running NM in the joist space is fine, if the panel is mounted in stud space then above panel should be ok, If panel is surface mounted could be up to local interpretation.

Comment: Panel is surface mounted since the walls are concrete, but it's mounted on top of a sheet of plywood which seems sufficient.

Comment: Inspectors vary on how strictly they enforce **NEC 334.15(B) Protection from Physical Damage.** Cable shall be protected from physical damage where necessary by rigid metal conduit, intermediate metal conduit, electrical metallic tubing, Schedule 80 PVC conduit, RTRC marked with the suffix -XW, or other approved means. Where passing through a floor, the cable shall be enclosed in rigid metal conduit, intermediate metal conduit, electrical metallic tubing, Schedule 80 PVC conduit, RTRC marked with the suffix -XW, or other approved means

Comment: extending at least 6 inches above the floor.  Conduit or tubing shall be provided with a bushing or adapter that provides protection from abrasion at the point the cable enters and exits the raceway.

Answer (score -2):

It should work fine, just follow proper wiring procedures. Check with your local code people, here GFCI receptacles are not allowed, other areas they are required.

Comment: Wait... GFCI receptacles are _not allowed_??? Are GFCI _breakers_ required instead? This makes little to no sense in either case...

Comment: Depend on your local code, that I why I suggested checking with them. Three years ago I was told to take mine out.

Comment: Very bizarre. Where do you live if you don't mind my asking... (General area, I don't need your street address!)

Comment: Ohio Valley and the reason given is if it trips the basement will flood.

Comment: More questions, but I'll stop now before we get yelled at for chat in the comments. Thanks for the clarification (I'm not too far west of you - Boiler Up! :)